# Amazon Windows Services for VPS, please advise

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, architecture, hosting

I need the VPS services for hosting my ASP.NET project.
However, it's not just asp.net hosting, I also need SQL Server, RabbitMq and either my running conrole app or my windows service.
So I read the suggestions to use Amazon Web Services as they provide first year for free.
However when I registered I found that I don't have a clue of where I am:
I don't see the option of creating a virtual machine with Windows
I don't see the option of setting up SQL Server on such the machine
and so on.
So I was wondering whether I'm in the right place?
Please advise if AWS can provide me with what I need or I came to the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

AWS can provide all that you listed, but you'll need to do some learning on your end.

Basically you create an EC2 instance, and then use RDP to remote into it, and you can install software and configure it to your hearts content - just like it was any other physical server.

If you want to use SQL Server, you'll have the choice of installing it directly on the instance using your own license, or using their 'hosted' version of SQL Server call RDS. You'll need to read about it and decide which option is better for your project - there is no single right way.

Lastly, I will point out that although the 'free-tier' is nice, except for a really small application (i.e. small db on a low traffic website), you may find out the 'free-tier' does not quite give you all the power you need to run a busy application. I would not base your decision on wether or not you should use AWS on how much 'free' stuff you can get. The free-tier is nice for learning, but plan on spending some money for a truly robust solution.